# Replace certain values in all tibble columns with NA

Tags: r, replace, dplyr, na, tidyverse

In the following tibble how to set the entries with only `"-"` to `NA`? I do not want to replace dash in entries like `"1-2"` with `NA`, only there where only dash is typed. I have a huge dataset so that would neet to apply to all columns and rows.
Thanks!

```
data_fake <- data.frame(c("1","2","-","3","2","1"),c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c("2-3","3 bundles","4","5","-","1"))

data_fake <- as_tibble(data_fake)

data_fake %>%
        recode(.,"-", NA)
```

Comment: `data_fake[data_fake=='-'] <- NA`?

Comment: or `data_fake %>% na_if("-")`

Comment: Such a simple nice command, fantastic and thank you so much! @lukeA!

Comment: and @MauritsEvers !